# draw color over a particular region based on condition in jframe

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I want to indicate status of a station by marking color over a region. Graphics2D class is used to draw color. It has to be updated continuously. I am using timer but it is not working. Any help is appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;

public class Station1 {

    public Station1(){

        Gradient gradient = new Gradient();
        JFrame f =  new JFrame("Input Carousel"); 
        f.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 

        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/input carousel.jpg"));
        label.setIcon(icon);

        gradient.add(label);
        f.add(gradient);

        f.pack();    
        f.setResizable(false); 
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); 
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
               new Station1();
            }
        });   
    }

    class Gradient extends JPanel{
    public Graphics2D g2D ;
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        g2D = (Graphics2D)g;
        AlphaComposite alphaComposite = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f);
        g2D.setComposite(alphaComposite);

        new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    try{
                        Jedis jedis = new Jedis("localhost");

                        if(jedis.get("b1").equals("1"))
                        {
                          g2D.setColor(Color.GREEN); 
                          g2D.fillRect(208, 172, 47, 75);
                        }
                        else if(jedis.get("b1").equals("e"))
                        {
                          g2D.setColor(Color.RED); 
                          g2D.fillRect(208, 172, 47, 75);
                        }

                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                        }  
            }
        }).start();

     }

    }    

}
```

If I run the code without timer it is working. If I use timer, it will not draw any color. 
Please suggest me solution for this problem.

Comment: Please see edit to answer. Ask if questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've several glaring issues with that code:

1. Starting a Timer within a painting method, a method that often gets called many times, most of which you have no control over
2. Calling what looks like potentially blocking code within a painting method (and within the Swing event thread). This may render your code completely useless as this can potentially freeze the gui

Suggestions:

1. Create the Timer and start it *once* and not within any painting method. Perhaps do this within a class's constructor
2. The timer should change fields of the class and call repaint
3. Your painting method should then use the state of these fields to decide what to paint and where
4. Don't forget to call the `super.paintComponent(g);` in your override, usually on its first line.
5. If creating Jedis means creating a long-running bit of code, do this within a background thread such as a SwingWorker
6. A painting method is for painting and painting only, and your code should respect this.

For example, please have a look at the code below. Note that I do not have access to your Jedis class (nor why you're using it), and so created a "mock" class. Also, I do not have access to your image, and so used a publicly available image for this demo program. I also sped up your timer.

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
// import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Station1 {
    private static final String IMG_PATH = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/"
            + "commons/thumb/f/f4/LINCOLN%2C_Abraham-President_%28BEP_engraved_portrait%29.jpg"
            + "/800px-LINCOLN%2C_Abraham-President_%28BEP_engraved_portrait%29.jpg";

    public Station1() {
        Gradient gradient = new Gradient();
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Input Carousel");
        f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JLabel label = new JLabel();

        // ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/input carousel.jpg"));

        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            URL imgUrl = new URL(IMG_PATH);
            img = ImageIO.read(imgUrl);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Icon icon = new ImageIcon(img);

        label.setIcon(icon);

        gradient.add(label);
        f.add(gradient);

        f.pack();
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Station1();
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    class Gradient extends JPanel {
        private JedisMock jedisMock = new JedisMock("localhost");
        private String jedisValue = "";

        public Gradient() {
            int timerDelay = 200;
            new Timer(timerDelay, new TimerListener()).start();
        }

        private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // may need to wrap this within a try/catch
                jedisValue = jedisMock.get("b1");
                repaint();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
            AlphaComposite alphaComposite = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER,
                    0.5f);
            g2D.setComposite(alphaComposite);
            if (jedisValue.equals("1")) {
                g2D.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g2D.fillRect(208, 172, 47, 75);
            } else if (jedisValue.equals("e")) {
                g2D.setColor(Color.RED);
                g2D.fillRect(208, 172, 47, 75);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

```
public class JedisMock {

    private String host;

    public JedisMock(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    // method to mock your method
    public String get(String text) {
        double randomValue = Math.random();
        if (randomValue < 0.333) {
            return "1";
        } else if (randomValue < 0.667) {
            return "e";
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```